# Zend Framework 2 - inject additional HTML on "finish"

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to inject additional HTML once all the processing is done in ZF2 project. So far, I tried to attach to the `finish` event in the main module via `onBootstrap()` function, like this:

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{

    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach("finish", function($e) {
        $renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewrenderer');
        $finalView = new ViewModel();
        $finalView->setTerminal(true);
        $finalView->setTemplate('global/layout');
        var_dump($renderer->render($finalView));
        exit;
    }, -1000);

}
```

... in this code, however, `getServiceLocator()` will return a null, even though my module ***implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface***.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

for the service manager:

```
    $application = $e->getApplication();
    $sm    = $application->getServiceManager();

$eventManager->attach("finish", function($e) use ($sm) {
    $renderer = $sm->get('viewrenderer');
    $finalView = new ViewModel();
    $finalView->setTerminal(true);
    $finalView->setTemplate('global/layout');
    var_dump($renderer->render($finalView));
    exit;
}, -1000);
```

Second,

The event:
I am not 100% sure, but I think it should be:

```
  $eventManager->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH , function($e) {
   ...
```

Comment: Yeeep, the EVENT_FINISH constant is just the string 'finish' but the convention is to use the defined constants from MvcEvent class

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()
```

and be done with the whole ServiceLocatorAwareInterface